# img url with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can someone help me with using the `img` tag with vue.js?

Per the vue.js [documentation](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#v-bind), I tried:

```
<img v-bind:src={{ imgURL }}> //prints a null image
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txmkLfad/)

Can someone help?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/202#issuecomment-207979862

Comment: Does my answer works?

Comment: v-bind:src="imgURL"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to **remove the double bracket:**

```
<img :src=imgURL>
```

You bind it with shorthand syntax, so we don't need 'v-bind' or '{{}}' braces, its beauty of VUE JS, ':' is used to bind.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
<img v-bind:src=imgURL>
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answers are both right but it doesn't really explains why the OP's making a mistake.

When you are using double brackets you are telling vue to do v-bind: so when you write v-bind and also use double brackets then you are double calling the same thus generating a mistaken behavior.

Short words: either use v-bind or double brackets {{ }}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to print an image from image binary code,

```
<img v-bind:src="'data:image/Bmp;base64,' + obj1.Obj2.propImage" />
```